# Adding Web Shortcut to iPhone Homescreen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-standalone-web-app

How can I BY CODE add a web shortcut to iPhone HomeScreen?

Comment: You can't, not without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to do this. Your best bet is to do what many web apps do: create something that points at the part of the toolbar where the add to homescreen button exists. And pray Apple doesn't change the position of that button any time soon.